# python script does not run from cron

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-10.04, pam

I have a python script "start.py" that executes well from the command line. There is only one statement in it (print "hello"). EDIT: start.py contains also a working interpreter directive in the first line.

As soon as I run the script from a cron job, every time it fires there is a message in syslog:

```
Jun  7 02:57:01 mit CRON[23275]: Module is unknown
```

I tried already to add PATH and PYTHONPATH information to the cron file:

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/my_cron
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6:/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
* * * * * mit /home/mit/dev/start.py
```

I found several answers and solutions that seem the same but nothing helped me. What am I missing?

Comment: It could be a file ownership or permission issue.

Comment: why do you even need 'mit' in your crontab?

Comment: Please post the contents of your script...the first line needs to specify your interpreter, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: That error message sounds more like `pam(7)` than Python or `cron(8)`. What is in your `/etc/pam.d/cron` file? Does it require modules that don't exist?

Comment: @Mike, perhaps the system administrator doesn't want to allow user `mit` to run _arbitrary_ cron events, but adding this one makes sense?

Comment: Looks like a PAM error. Have you updated PAM recently? Perhaps crond needs to be restarted

Comment: @Mike I am not sure what you are suggesting, you mean I could exchange mit for root in the crontab line?

Comment: @mit, I'm saying that many times, there is no value in specifying a user to run as...

Comment: @Mike how would I run without a user? You mean as root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recent update of PAM broke cron. Try restarting your computer (or restarting cron with `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`)

Comment: i will try. I noticed the cron script worked before, but did not execute at some point in time anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much. A cron restart did it. : )

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add python in front of it.

```
* * * * * mit /usr/bin/python /home/mit/dev/start.py
```

Comment: That might not be an issue if the file is chmoded to executable and it contains an interpreter directive as the first line.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete posting. I had tried all combinations with or without python, also the shebang line with correct interpreter is there. the script works from the commandline when I start '/home/mit/dev/start.py' as user 'mit'